# Jupyter Variables doens't work on this code in VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I think that I found a little issue with Jupyter Notebook in Python scripts ends in extensions *.py

I have installed this extensions to VSC: Bracket Pair Colorizer, Dracula PyCharm Theme, Jupyter, Jupyter Keymap, MagicPython, Pylance, Python, Python for VSCode.

On code below when I running cell, than I trying to explorer variables I had an error "Failed to create the Data Viewer. Check the Jupyter tab of the Output window for more info."

```
#%%
url = 'https://e-smartdata.teachable.com/p/sciezka-data-scientist-machine-learning-engineer'
list = url[::1].split('/')
list2 = list
code = str(list[4])
print(code.replace('-',' '))
```

[image: Error in Jupyter Variables]

But when I create new *.py file with clear data for example:

> #%% a = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]

I am able to explore variables

[image: Working Jupyter Variables]

I am trying to resolve this problem for three days. I decide to ask older colleagues :)

Best Regards,
Paul

Comment: You've overridden the `list()` built-in function and you never use `list2`